# Include jar libraries in rawr jar

Tags: ruby, jar, embed, jruby, embedding

I'm using [rawr](http://rawr.rubyforge.org/) to create a jar from JRuby, and there are a couple java libraries (in jar form) that I want to use. This works fine, but it puts a copy of the folder containing them inside both the resulting package *and* in the package's directory. When I run it, it works fine, but how can I package *all* files completely inside the result? If I delete the folder containing the libraries in the newly created package's parent directory, it throws an error.

EDIT: Also here's my `build_config.rb`:

```
configuration do |c|
  c.project_name = "LWJGL Tutorial"
  c.output_dir = "package"
  c.main_ruby_file = "tutorial"
  c.main_java_file = "org.rubyforge.rawr.Main"

  c.source_dirs = ["./"]
  c.source_exclude_filter = []

  c.compile_ruby_files = true
  c.java_lib_dirs = ["lib/java"]
end
```